# Prawn is taking more time to load the images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I m developing an application where i m giving functionality to export a pdf report with multiple images. It is working fine with pdf prawn. But loading time of report is more if i m rendering images. If i dont render images pdf file is exported very quickly. Is there any way to reduce the loading time or to compress the image file before render in pdf files.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's just the report's file size. In that case using smaller or compressed images would help.

Comment: Is thr any method in prawn so that i can compress iamge before rendering it in pdf files.

Comment: AFAIK an image is inserted "as-is". You have to scale/compress the image yourself.

Comment: Actually pdf writing time is more.. not getting report time